# What microbial contaminant grows blue on L-agar/L-broth and is resistant to carbenicillin?

Tags: microbiology

We are trying to grow liquid cultures of *Mycobacterium smegmatis* as a host for bacteriophages, but we have been having issues with contamination. Our latest attempt went like this:

- Tuesday 1 pm: Added 20 ml 7H9 broth, 2 ml Albumine-Dextrose solution, 0.02g CaCl2, one colony from master *M. smegmatis* culture was added to 100 ml Erlenmeyer flask. Incubated in a shaker at 35° C.
- Wednesday 6pm: Added 20 ul of carbenicillin (should have been added from the top, but the carbenicillin arrived a day late)
- Thursday 1pm: liquid culture is turbid white and clumpy as expected.
- Friday 2pm: Culture is still turbid white and clumpy. Inoculated a streak on left half of L-agar plate.
- Saturday 3pm: Streak plate shows streaks of yellow-white colonies (as expected), but also a blue diffuse contaminant which smells very bad. This is similar to what we've seen in our previous attempt at growing this culture

Now, the question is: What could this blue contaminant be? The original culture protocol used Cycloheximide to control for fungal growth, but ours has not arrived yet.

A related question is. Where could it have come from?

### Master *M. smegmatis* culture

[image: Master M.smegmatis culture]

### Liquid *M. smegmatis* culture

[image]

### Contaminated streak plate

[image: Contaminated streak plate]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Pseudomonas aeruginosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudomonas_aeruginosa) is a likely candidate. This is a common skin organism and cultures/colonies often have a blue/green sheen. Pure cultures generally have a fruity/ester smell.

The blue/green pigment is a combination of pyoverdine and pyocyanin.

Of note is that it is also commonly antibiotic resistant having intrinsic antibiotic resistance to a range of antibiotics, [including the penicillin group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudomonas_aeruginosa#Treatment)